# How to consume WEB Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have created one web service to save error log

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;
using System.Net.Mail;

using System.IO;

namespace TestErrorHandling
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public int SaveErrorLog(CompositeType objCom)
        {
            int messageId = 0;

            try
            {
                SqlDatabase _errDBConnection = null;
                _errDBConnection = new SqlDatabase(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ErrorLogConnStr"].ToString());

                DbCommand dbCommand = _errDBConnection.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_SaveErrorLog");
                _errDBConnection.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@i_ApplicationId", DbType.Int32, objCom.AppId);
                _errDBConnection.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@i_ExceptionType", DbType.String, objCom.ExceptionType);
                _errDBConnection.AddOutParameter(dbCommand, "@O_MESSAGEID", DbType.Int32, 4);
                _errDBConnection.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);
                messageId = Convert.ToInt32(_errDBConnection.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "@O_MESSAGEID"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                   throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
            }
            return messageId;
        }


    }
}
```

Now I am calling this service in my web application

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Test.ServiceReference1;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class _Default : BasePage
    {
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj1 = new  ServiceReference1.Service1Client;

                obj1.

}
```

But after typing obj1. its not showing SaveErrorLog method of Service.
Please help on this where I am doing wrong.

added like  [image]

Comment: How did you add reference to webservice in web application?

Comment: I have added reference through Add Web reference

Comment: Is the `SaveErrorLog` method in the `IService1` interface decorated with `[OperationContract]`?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj1 = new  ServiceReference1.Service1Client;
```

to

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj1 = new  ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
```

and then use

```
obj1.<method name>
```

also add reference using add service references

like this..
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes I used ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj1 = new  ServiceReference1.Service1Client(); still obj1. method name not coming

Comment: try adding service reference instead of web reference